# Header has unexplainable height

Tags: html, css, header, height

I don't know why, but my h3 seems to have a massive height, I have a second h3 further down the page, which doesn't have this problem at all, no matter what margin or padding I set for the top of h3, it will always be somewhere above the picture background, where the nav is?

[image]

HTML

```
<header>
<div class="fixed">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="work/index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="travel/index.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>

    <div class="picture">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <h2 class="name">Betti</h2>
    </div>
</header>

<main>

    <h3>Website Project</h3>
    <p>coded in HTML &amp; CSS</p>

    <div class="project">
      <a href="../project1/index.html" target="_blank">   
      <img class="box" id="project1" src="../project1/img/project1.jpg" alt="project1"></a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.fixed{
position: fixed;
background-color: white;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: dashed;
border-color: #666666;
}

.picture{
background: url("../img/london.jpg") no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
margin-top: 0%;
width: 100%;
float: left;
border-left: solid #a5053d;
border-width: 15px;
}

 h1{
padding: 1% 0 0 4%;
text-transform: uppercase;
float: left;
left: 0;
}

 h2{
padding: 0 4%;
color: white;
float: left;
margin-top: 3%;
}

h3{
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: -20px; 
margin-top: 0;
}

#project1, #project2{
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: auto;
width: 60%;
text-align: center;
border: 1.9px solid #a5053d;
margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.project{
clear: both;
float: none;
overflow: none;
position: center;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a live link of the site?

Comment: @AndrewLyndem - Pasting the code here into a fiddle is sufficient to reproduce the issue the OP describes.

Comment: @BSMP Yes, it is sufficient to reproduce the issue but I just prefer debugging certain css issues (like this one) on live sites itself if possible. If it's not possible for the OP to provide the link, then the provided code snippets can be used.

Comment: padding-top:1% means 1% of the width of its parent :(  https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties  (idem for vertical margin using percentage)  **just realized i mistook h1 and h3 css  ....**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just seeing space that `main` is taking up. It's consuming all of that space because the element before it, `header`, has floated children and `header` doesn't have a clearfix. So `main` technically starts where `header` ends, but is below the children in `header`.

You can address that by clearing the floats in `header`, then `main` won't appear so tall and will actually start where `header` ends. I added `overflow: auto;` to `header` but there are other ways to clear floats, too. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZbmKV

```css
header {
  overflow: auto;
}

.fixed{
position: fixed;
background-color: white;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: dashed;
border-color: #666666;
}

.picture{
background: url("../img/london.jpg") no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
margin-top: 0%;
width: 100%;
float: left;
border-left: solid #a5053d;
border-width: 15px;
}

 h1{
padding: 1% 0 0 4%;
text-transform: uppercase;
float: left;
left: 0;
}

 h2{
padding: 0 4%;
color: white;
float: left;
margin-top: 3%;
}

h3{
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: -20px; 
margin-top: 0;
}

#project1, #project2{
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: auto;
width: 60%;
text-align: center;
border: 1.9px solid #a5053d;
margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.project{
clear: both;
float: none;
overflow: none;
position: center;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
<div class="fixed">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="work/index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="travel/index.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>

    <div class="picture">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <h2 class="name">Betti</h2>
    </div>
</header>

<main>

    <h3>Website Project</h3>
    <p>coded in HTML &amp; CSS</p>

    <div class="project">
      <a href="../project1/index.html" target="_blank">   
      <img class="box" id="project1" src="../project1/img/project1.jpg" alt="project1"></a>
    </div>
```